# Is there a way to edit a many to many relationship in laravel and nuxt

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

So i have a create post page that has category in it for users to attach to a post they want to create.

So when a user wants to create a post they can add an image.

But when the user wants to edit the post the category that was created with the post gets displayed but once unticked it is removed from the database and no category is displayed on the edit page.

How can i make sure that even though category is unchecked it displays fresh ones for the user to check.

I have this in my vue edit page.

```
 <div class="mt-2">
                            <span class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">Categories</span>
                            <div v-if="categories ? categories.length : 0">
                              <div v-for="(category, i) in categories" :key="i">
                                <label class="inline-flex items-center">
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" v-model="category.id" 
                                    :value="category.id"
                                  >
                                  <span class="ml-2" v-html="category.name"></span>
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div v-else>
                              <div v-for="(mainCategory, i) in mainCategories" :key="i">
                                <label class="inline-flex items-center">
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" v-model="catSelected" 
                                    :value="mainCategory.id"
                                  >
                                  <span class="ml-2" v-html="mainCategory.name"></span>
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

Script.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
  name: 'PostEdit',
  components:{
    LeftBar,
    TopBar,
    Footer,
    PostError,
    'editor': Editor
  },
  data:() =>({
    errors: [],
    title: '',
    body: '',
    excerpt: '',
    categories: [],
    mainCategories: [],
    catSelected: [],
  }),
  async fetch(){
    await this.$axios.get('/api/post/'+this.$route.params.id)
    .then(response => {
      this.title = response.data.post.title
      this.body = response.data.post.body
      this.excerpt = response.data.post.excerpt
      this.categories = response.data.categories
      this.mainCategories = response.data.mainCategories
    })
  },
  methods: {
    async updatePost(){
      this.errors = []
      await this.$axios.put('/api/post/update/'+this.$route.params.id , {
        title: this.title,
        body: this.body,
        excerpt: this.excerpt,
        categories: this.categories.id,
        mainCategories: this.catSelected
      }).then(()=> this.$router.push('/posts'))
      .catch(error => {
        if(error.response.status !== 422) throw error

        this.errors = Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat()
      })

    },
    async updateCategories(){
        console.log(this.categories)
    },
    goBack(){
      this.$router.go(-1)
    }
  },
  head(){
    return{
      title: 'Update Post - ' + this.title
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

PostController

```
 * Display/Edit the specified post.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $mainCat = Category::all();
        $cat = $post->categories()->get();
        return response()->json([
            'post' => $post, 
            'categories' => $cat,
            'mainCategories' => $mainCat
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(PostRequest $request, Post $post)
    {
        $post->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'excerpt' => $request->excerpt,
        ]);

        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        $post->categories()->sync($request->mainCategories);

        return response()->json([
            'post' => $post,
            'message' => 'Post updated successfully.'
        ], 200);
    }
```

Comment: I guess no one knows this???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when you edit the post and unselect the category, you want it to show all the list of the category for the user to select the new category right?

then it's simple, you just need to fetch the category list and show it with v-if when there is no record of category selected for the related post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @fendy I think you need to give an example